# [Microchip][Mplab X IDE v5.35] Makefile-default.mk has some problem when build source

Tags: makefile, microcontroller, pic, mplab, xc8

【Environment】

OS: Windows 64bit

Software: Mplab X IDE v5.35

Compiler: XC8 (v2.10)

【Step】

Menu -> Production -> Build Main Project

【phenomenon】

Build failed.

> make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJRPq.png): *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:107: build/default/production/main.p1] Error -1073741515
>
> make[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYok7.png): *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:91: .build-conf] Error 2
>
> make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: .build-impl] Error 2

Here is my screen capture.
[image: mplab5.35 build failed screen]

【Supplement】

In the same thing (just use [**mplab X IDE v3.55]**) build sucess.

Here is [image: Makefile-default.mk]

Here is [image: Makefile-impl.mk]

【Question】

What happen in mplab5.35? Must I install other library?

Thanks you!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Post file contents and error messages as text, not as images, please. And just in case: if you need to add more information, please [edit] your question, don't write a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makefiles in MPLAB can occationally have various issues between IDE version.

See if you can regenerate your makefiles. If you look at MPLAB® X IDEUser’s Guide in Appendix "B.4 CREATING MAKEFILES OUTSIDE OF MPLAB X IDE" (DS50002027D-page 284)

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/50002027d.pdf

You can see that MPLAB X when creating a new project will call `prjMakefileGenerator.bat` from it's platform tool binary folder. For example in my windows system this batch file is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\v5.35\mplab_platform\bin\prjMakefilesGenerator.bat`, which I call in the project folder to regenerate all the makefiles except for `$PROJECT_DIR/Makefile`. Usually I call it as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\MPLABX\v5.35\mplab_platform\bin\prjMakefilesGenerator.bat .` in the project folder where `.` is the path (pointing to the current folder).

This should hopefully fix most problems relating to generated makefile differences between MPLAB X IDE versions.

### B.4.2 The `prjMakefilesGenerator` utility is found at:

- Windows:  `$inst_mplabx\mplab_ide\bin\prjMakefilesGenerator.bat`
- Linux OS: `$inst_mplabx/mplab_ide/bin/prjMakefilesGenerator.sh`
- Mac OS X: `$inst_mplabx/mplab_ide.app/Contents/Resources/mplab_ide/bin/prjMakefilesGenerator.sh`

Comment: Hello @Brian, how do you create `$PROJECT_DIR/Makefile`? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure. If I recall, that makefile is not autogenerated and is meant to be user editable. So you should perhaps try creating a new empty project of the same MCU type and copy over the Makefile to your location.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a compatibility problem between Mplab X IDE versions.

According to this [document](https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:v5-compatibility) you have to choose **Yes** when you open an old project with a newer MpLab version, so that it could modify all generated files, which are necessary for compiler to build the project.

You should also consider the fact that a newer version of MpLab comes also with a newer compiler version, which off course could be changed back to the older version in project settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But i used MPLaB 5.35 to create a new project, not open an old version file.
A file has just created in MPlab 5.35 in compatible compiler, and make error.  :((